# Determining if a question is right for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, scope

I was reading this page here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, or anyone who writes code because they love it. The best Stack Overflow questions generally have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers; and is**
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

So I was going to open a question asking if MaxScale by [MariaDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB) is a good choice or if they are better alternatives.

I know this can fall under the umbrella of an opinion-based question. I think it is a really good question as there is not much information out there about database proxies, how useful they are, and what options are good for developers.

So I am not looking for an answer to the MaxScale question here, but I am looking to determine if this would be a proper question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Note that MariaDB and especially MariaDB MaxScale is hardly unique to software development and I would expects tons of people who aren't programmers to more commonly be involved with it.

Comment: "if MaxScale by mariadb is a good choice or if they are better alternatives" is 2 questions. "better" means nothing in particular. [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)
[Why was my "shopping list" question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/266284) (And given a "better" how/where are you stuck deciding/evaluating goodness/betterness?)

Comment: I see so no matter how you really phrase it. it boils down to im looking for a recommendation which would not be on topic

Comment: At least not here - there is, however, [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: @CherryDT Thank you I never actually knew this site existed. This might be a good site to add to the bottom of the list https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JoséphFlames In this case [there may be more sites that are new to you](https://stackexchange.com/sites) ;-)

Comment: In general asking if something one solution is better than another solution, will make the question, out of scope.  Likewise, asking for a list of alternatives, would also make the question out of scope.  If you an opinion on a subject, then SO is unlikely the community to provide that opinion, since questions that have opinion based answers are out of scope. If you need a professional opinion, you should hire somebody, to provide you the positives and negatives of each solution

Comment: "How to accomplish <well-defined task> with MariaDB?" is valid, and probably even a good question if you show examples of what you've tried and found wanting.

Comment: Note that you should have bolded the fourth point as well. Notice how there is an "; and is" stuck to the end of the part you bolded, not an "or". Nicely written, eh?

Answer (score 14):

[It wouldn't; we're not capable of making a decision like this for you.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

We work best with concrete questions, not questions that ask us to shop around to make an objective comparison.  We don't know your requirements, and unless you hire us we won't know your requirements, so this sort of thing is really best handled by you doing that leg work.

Comment: So then a better way to phrase this would be 

"I am looking into MaxScale because I am looking for something to seperate the code from the database architecture while also having this software automatically handle load balancing and handling promoting a new master. Is there an open source alternative to accomplish this?"

Comment: @JoséphFlames That would likely be asking for recommendations, which [isn't on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) either.

Answer (score 6):

From [the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), lower down:

> **Some questions that fit into one of the categories listed above may be closed by the community because they aren't generally a good fit here or need additional information:**
>
> [...]
>
> 3. Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.